# How would I show a functional is linear and bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Using the following results, for any $f \in H^1(a,b)$, $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, and therefore, $$ \int_a^b f(x) dx = f(\zeta)$$ for some $\zeta \in (a,b)$. In addition $$f(c) = f(\zeta) + \int_\zeta^c f'(x)dx.$$ How would I go about showing the functional defined as  $\ell \in (H^1 (a,b))'$ by $$ \ell(v) = v(c), v \in H^1 (a,b)$$ for some $c \in [a,b]$, is linear and bounded on $H^1(a,b)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have all the ingredients ready:

To show that $\ell$ is bounded, we need $|\ell(f)| \le C||f||_{H^1}$ for some $C$. Now there is $\zeta$ (depending on $f$) so that

$$\ell(f) = f(c) = f(\zeta) + \int_\zeta^c f'(x)dx = \int_a^b f(x) dx + \int_\zeta^c f'(x)dx$$

Then

$$|\ell (f)| \le \int_a^b |f(x) |dx + \int_\zeta^c |f'(x)| dx \le \cdots$$

Comment: Would it then be appropriate for me to use The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for Lebesgue Integral?

Comment: Can I do the following?

$$|\ell(f)|\le \int_a^b|f(x)|dx+\int_\zeta^c|f'(x)|dx$$ $$< \int_a^b|f(x)|dx+|f(\zeta)-f(c)|\le\int_a^b|f(x)|dx+|f(\zeta)|-|f(c)|$$ $$\le\int_a^b|f(x)|dx+|f(\zeta)|=\int_a^b|f(x)|dx + \int_a^b|f(x)|dx$$ $$ = C(\int_a^b|f(x)|dx)=C||f||_{H^1}$$

Comment: @Xelda: For your last sentence, that is not true. (What is $||f||_{H^1}$?)

Comment: $||f|| = sup \{|\ell(f)|$  |  $\ell \in H', ||\ell||=1\}$ and $||f||_{H^1}$ means that norm is in the space of $H^1(a,b)$ @John

Comment: @Xelda: The $H^!$ norm is given by $||f||_{H^1} = \int_a^b |f| + \int_a^b |f'|$.

Comment: Great thanks, is this correct? $ \int_a^b f(x) dx +  \int_a^b f(x) dx \le C(\int_a^b f(x) dx +  \int_a^b f'(x) dx) = C||f||_{H^1}$

Comment: Yes. (If you have the absolute sign). In this case $C=1$ indeed.

Comment: $ \int_a^b |f(x)| dx +  \int_a^b |f(x)| dx \le C(\int_a^b |f(x)| dx +  \int_a^b |f'(x)| dx) = C||f||_{H^1}$ Great, thanks! @john